# Is there any simple functions or cleaner implementation to successive column differences for an xts object?

Tags: r, vector, xts, subtraction

Can anyone improve on this implementation?

```
nn = 1:(ncol(dataList[['Implied']])-1)
dataList[['CS Implied']] = lapply(nn, function (x) (dataList$'Implied'[,x] - dataList$'Implied'[,x+1])/dataList$'Implied'[,x])
dataList[['CS Implied']] = do.call(cbind,dataList[['CS Implied']])
names(dataList[['CS Implied']]) = paste0("Spread ", nn, "-", nn + 1)
```

Comment: If you provide `dataList` (a small manageable version), you're more likely to get an answer from someone.

Comment: Thanks for the advice